# Как избавится от return null в фабрике Connection'ов к DB?

Tags: java

У меня есть метод-фабрика который возвращает мне новые соединения с DB но мне не нравится что при использовании `try-catch` в случае неудачи мне приходится возвращать `null`.

```
public Connection get() {

    try {

        return DriverManager.getConnection(
                "url",
                "username",
                "password");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null; //вот тут.
}
```

Помогите мне избавится от этого `null` так чтобы не пробрасывать исключение через сигнатуру метода.

Comment: throw e и вызов придется оборачивать в try-catch; либо делайте switch-case с проверкой характера ошибки - неправильный юзер/пароль, не удается подключиться к серверу - и более умным throw...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться классом `java.util.Optional`.

```
public Optional<Connection> get() {
    try {
        return Optional.of(DriverManager.getConnection(
            "url",
            "username",
            "password"));
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ...  избавится от этого null так чтобы не пробрасывать исключение через сигнатуру метода.

Чтобы избавиться от `return` в конце `catch` должен либо выбросить исключение, либо вернуть значение. Рассмотрим оба варианта.

1. `catch` выбросит исключение.

`throw e` выбросит `SQLException`, что потребует явного объявления исключения в сигнатуре. Такой подход гарантирует, что код, обращающийся к методу, будет вынужден обработать исключение.

Если по каким-то причинам (например, если обработка исключений отделена от логики) требуется не включать исключение в сигнатуру метода, то можно создать новое непроверяемое исключение.

```
//определение
class ConnectException extends RuntimeException {
    ConnectException(SQLException sqle) {
        super(sqle);
    }
}

//использование
} catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new ConnectException(e);
}
```

Это избавит от необходимости объявлять исключение в вызывающих методах, но не избавит от необходимости его обрабатывать.

2. `catch` что-либо вернет. Этот вариант тождествен варианту с `return` в конце метода. Что именно возвращать зависит от требований к этому методу. Варианты:

   - `null`;
   - [Null Object](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_(%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F));
   - свой класс, например обертку `Connection`, которая будет содержать статус ошибки.

Перечисленные варианты несколько неочевидны: от метода `get` ожидается, что он либо вернет значение, либо, если это невозможно, выбросит исключение.

Comment: Делать исключение непроверяемым, чтобы при использовании метода  потом забыть про его существование (кто же будет писать документацию к методу...) и обвалить полпрограммы из-за отсутствия `try-catch`? По-моему, это весьма сомнительный вариант, хоть он и принят в C#.

Comment: @Regent по-хорошему, чтобы обработать на другом уровне. Согласен, что все может быть очень плохо, особенно без тестов/документации. Однако `throws SQLException` на всех методах не панацея — уже на один уровень выше смысл потеряется и исключение будут глотать.